# Почему в результате получается 1?

Tags: javascript

```
function one(foo) { return 1 + foo || 1 }
function minus(bar) { return - bar}

console.log(one(minus(one())));
```

Comment: @VerNick, тут все ок, это javascript

Comment: @Grundy Блин, чего это меня понесло... напрограммировался на си))

Comment: кстати, а какой результат ожидался от этого выражения?

Comment: ожидалось, что результат будет 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы понять результат конечного выражения, нужно выполнить его по шагам и посмотреть результат на каждом шаге.

Выражение `one(minus(one()))` можно представить в следующем виде:

```
var a = one();
var b = minus(a);
var c = one(b);
```

Посмотрим результат на каждом шаге:

1. `var a = one()`. так как параметр `one` - `undefined` - `(1 + undefined) || 1` -> `NaN || 1` -> `1`
2. `var b = minus(1)`. Результат `-1`
3. `var c = one(-1)` -> `(1 + (-1)) || 1` -> `0 || 1` -> 1

Почему так происходит?

Все это из-за того, что приоритет операции `||` меньше чем приоритет сложения.

---

> ожидалось, что результат будет 0

Для этого необходимо поправить функцию `one`.

Вместо `foo||1` нужно писать `foo||0`. Чтобы в случае отсутствия аргумента функция возвращала `1`, а не `2` как сейчас:

```js
function one(foo) {
  return 1 + (foo || 0)
}

function minus(bar) {
  return -bar
}

console.log(one(minus(one())));
```

Comment: Благодарю. Это решение помогло.

Comment: @БашкатовСергей, можешь отметить ответ галочкой

Answer (score 1):

Возьмите `foo || 1` в скобки

```js
function one(foo) {
  return 1 + (foo || 1);
}

function minus(bar) {
  return 0 - bar;
}
console.log(one(minus(one())));
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас выполняется второе выражение, потому что внутренняя функция `one()` ничего не принимает. `foo` ничему не равен и, соответственно выполняется второе выражение. Просто надо подумать.